# Listen to Oracle AQ through VPN

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-aq

I am trying to receive notifications from My DB which is in a data center. When i am on the same network as of the DB i can receive the notifications but when connected through VPN No Notifications are there. Can any one tell how can i listen to the AQ through VPN also.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use TCP keeplalive to periodically "refresh" status of your DB connection.

See:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/207410/sockets/java/Java-Oracle-JDBC-Linux-KeepAlive
https://rubyorchard.wordpress.com/2007/04/07/oracle-jdbc-connection-keepalive/

But you will also need Administrator/root privileges to perform the OS level configuration part.

Another option (preferred) would be listening with timeout. So your code will contain an infinite loop and will handle (ingnore) ORA-25228 error.

Answer (score 0):

With the Oracle JDBC Thin driver, when you call connection.registerAQNotification, you can set global options (the third parameter) and one of the option is the local host's IP address (OracleConnection.NTF_LOCAL_HOST). When connecting over the VPN you need to set this option to your IP address over the VPN.